# How to limit Google maps' search to specific services near the current location?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an Android App that provide users with the nearby hospital and clinic informations. The app will get users location via GPS and searches on its own for the nearby medical assistance. I'm using Google maps for my app.

Can anyone teach how to limit the Google maps' search to only display the hospitals and clinics around user's location please?

Thank you.

Comment: what you had tried.?